# What's a sphere in the space of matrices?

Tags: matrices, spheres, spectral-norm

Given a normed vector space $V$ over a field $k$ it's sphere is the set of points of unit norm.

$$ S(V) = \{ v \in V \mid 1 = \lVert v \rVert^2 \}$$

Over the reals the n-spheres are just spheres of free modules.

$$ S^n = S(\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}) $$

Not sure about the terminology here for using fields other than the reals.

Anyhow suppose you want the sphere over matrices?

Assuming a Euclidean norm the sphere over m by n matrices ought to be the set of matrices with largest singular value equal to 1 (using the spectral norm.)

$$ S([\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m]) = \{ A \in [\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m] \mid 1 = \lVert A \rVert^2 \}$$

We want the largest (in magnitude) root of the characteristic polynomial to be 1. Plugging in 1 or -1 we get.

$$ \det(A^*A - \text{I}_n) = 0 $$

And

$$ \det(A^*A + \text{I}_n) = 0 $$

But this doesn't really make any sense to me and I can't visualize this. It just seems like weird symbols.

Is there a geometric picture of this?

I have a hunch spheres ought to be reducible to combinations of simpler n-spheres (might require axiom of choice) but I don't have the knowledge for such things.

Comment: Topological speaking it is the disjoint union of two connected components. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group)

Comment: @Ninad Munshi Can you elaborate? It seems like you are simplifying to square matrices or something. Orthogonal matrices seem correct to me as part of the solution even I don't understand it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the following picture is geometric *per se*, but perhaps you can get some intuition for it by considering what choices of the components of the singular value decomposition of $A$ make it such that $A$ is in the unit sphere of matrices.

If $A$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix, then the singular value decomposition will be of the form $$A = U\Sigma V$$
where $U$ is an $m \times m$ real orthogonal matrix, $\Sigma$ is a $m \times n$ real diagonal matrix whose entries are the singular values of $A$, and $V$ is a real $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix.

Notice that as long as we satisfy the singular value requirement in $\Sigma$, both $U$ and $V$ can be any orthogonal matrices of the appropriate size. Therefore, we would expect this sphere of matrices to be a direct product of the sets of all such orthogonal matrices, with whatever the set of possible $\Sigma$ matrices is. If we call the set of all orthogonal matrices of size $n$ to be $\mathbf{O}(n)$, then:

$$S([\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m]) = \mathbf{O}(m)\times\text{something}\times\mathbf{O}(n)$$

The number of independent parameters in an orthogonal matrix, i.e. the dimension of $\mathbf{O}(m)$, is $\frac{m^2-m}{2}$. So this gives you a sense that this sphere is at least $\frac{(m^2-m)(n^2-n)}{4}$ dimensional.

Now to $\Sigma$. The idea is that the largest value in $\Sigma$ must be $1$, and $\Sigma$ can have at most $p = \min(m,n)$ distinct singular values by definition. So the set of valid $\Sigma$ matrices appears to contain $p-1$ independently chosen numbers from $[0,1]$, one $1$ to satisfy the constraint, and some repetition of the singular values chosen previously in the remaining $m + n - 1 - p$ slots.

If we called this set $\mathbf{\Sigma_1}$, then $$S([\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m]) = \mathbf{O}(m)\times\mathbf{\Sigma_1}\times\mathbf{O}(n)$$
but this is basically the same thing I wrote above; just "something".

Under the caveat that I am being very imprecise, we can say that
$$S([\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m]) \approx \mathbf{O}(m)\times[0,1]^{\min(m,n) -1}\times \left\{1\right\}^\left({\min(m,n)\choose m+n-1-\min(m,n)}\right)\times\mathbf{O}(n)$$

The reason for this crude and imprecise statement is that we effectively have $p - 1 = \min(m,n) - 1$ independent values between $0$ and $1$ to pick for $\Sigma$, and $\left({\min(m,n)\choose m+n-1-\min(m,n)}\right)$ ways to distribute the $p-1$ numbers we picked, plus the required $1$, to the remaining $m+n-1-p$ slots on the diagonal of $\Sigma$.

The reason this is only approximate is because this is only valid when every selected number of those $p-1$ numbers is distinct; this combinatorial argument doesn't work when one of those selected numbers is repeated, and also doesn't consider other restrictions that may arise on the values in $\Sigma$ for specific choices of $U$ and $V$, but at least hopefully gives some sense of the approximate "geometry" or "structure" of the sphere.

Comment: I feel like you would probably want some kind of wedge product for sphere stuff instead of direct product? Still a far better answer than I could come up with.

Comment: You might be right—I avoided wedge products in case I made any incorrect assumptions about the induced topology of this sphere from that metric, and how wedge products “work” on that kind of topological space. I’ll think a bit about that and see if I can improve my answer.

Comment: I think wedge product was a mistaken intuition. Singular values correspond to scaling transformations right? So I think the ball of matrices ought to be matrices that only contract, reflect or rotate. The sphere is kind of tricky to think about.